# Problems using Realm on asp.net: DLL not found realms-wrapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, realm

I'm trying to use Realm on Asp.net. I've created a new C# Asp.net Web Forms Application from scratch and added latest Realm 4.3.0. Then I followed the [example on realm.io](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest) and created a new class 'Dog.cs'. In my default.aspx.cs I placed the code to access Realm but it always crashes already on first call `var realm = Realm.GetInstance();` with *System.TypeInitializationException: DllNotFoundException: "realm-wrappers" not found.*

Files I've added to the default ASP.net solution from scratch:

Dog.cs:

```
using Realms;

namespace RealmTest
{
    public class Dog : RealmObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using Realms;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace RealmTest
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var realm = Realm.GetInstance();

            // Use LINQ to query
            var puppies = realm.All<Dog>().Where(d => d.Age < 2);

            puppies.Count(); // => 0 because no dogs have been added yet

            // Update and persist objects with a thread-safe transaction
            realm.Write(() =>
            {
                realm.Add(new Dog { Name = "Rex", Age = 1 });
            });

            // Queries are updated in realtime
            puppies.Count(); // => 1

            // LINQ query syntax works as well
            var oldDogs = from d in realm.All<Dog>() where d.Age > 8 select d;

            // Query and update from any thread
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                var realm2 = Realm.GetInstance();

                var theDog = realm2.All<Dog>().Where(d => d.Age == 1).First();
                realm2.Write(() => theDog.Age = 3);
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

FodyWeavers.xml (created automatically)

```
<Weavers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FodyWeavers.xsd">
  <Realm />
</Weavers>
```

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: @papafe No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Did you also try with the latest version of Realm?

Comment: @papafe It was the latest version at the time of writing, but I stopped some days later as i did not find a solution. I don't know whether it's working with current latest version.